# Error installing libapache2-mod-rpaf for detecting IPs using nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy

I've seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/545531/remote-addr-doesnt-work-after-apache-upgrade), that I should install `mod_rpaf` so that Apache will be able to detect the IPs coming from the Nginx reverse proxy.

Even seen that there is a bug on [Ununtu SO](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache2-mod-rpaf/+bug/1126233), and it should be solved changing the first line on `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.conf`.

The first line contains `<IfModule rpaf_module>`. I've tried replacing with `<IfModule mod_rpaf-2.0.c>`, but nothing changes when I restart the Apache.

This is the output when I try to install this module:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-rpaf 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-rpaf
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,126 B of archives.
After this operation, 67.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-rpaf.
(Reading database ... 28714 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libapache2-mod-rpaf (from .../libapache2-mod-rpaf_0.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-rpaf (0.6-2ubuntu1) ...
Enabling module rpaf.
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rpaf.load: API module structure 'rpaf_module' in file /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rpaf.so is garbled - expected signature 41503234 but saw 41503232 - perhaps this is not an Apache module DSO, or was compiled for a different Apache version?
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-rpaf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-rpaf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The naming wouldn't really matter because it's a signature error. Have you tried grabbing it from a different repo or compiling it yourself? Next, do you _really_ need the module? Is nginx configured correctly to pass the IP's through (see: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/forwarding-visitors-real-ip/). Also, you could just drop Apache entirely and just use nginx. The site will go faster without Apache.

Answer (score 3):

Per the error, you already have a version of /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rpaf.so on your system with a filehash that differs from what the package config is expecting (expected signature 41503234 but saw 41503232), so you either need to:

1) Work out what installed the conflicting version and uninstall it:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rpaf.so
apt-get --purge remove <package>
```

Or if manually added:

```
mv /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rpaf.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rpaf.so.bak
apt-get install libapache2-mod-rpaf
```

This may break other stuff.

2) Manually download, [re-compile and install from source](http://www.yourhowto.net/install-and-enable-apache-modules-on-debian-ubuntu/), should solve the immediate issue, but you'll hit the same conflicting signature issue if you try to update via apt.

3) [Unpack the deb file, hack the hash in the config, repackage and install.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138188/easily-unpack-deb-edit-postinst-and-repack-deb)

Comment: It seems that `http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/download/mod_rpaf-0.6.tar.gz` is not responding (`wget http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/download/mod_rpaf-0.6.tar.gz`).

Comment: As I commented, I'm having some trouble to make it work. Anyway, I'll award you as you have tried it. Do you now how could I solve it?

Comment: There are other hosts e.g. https://nginxda.googlecode.com/files/mod_rpaf-0.6.tar.gz